# Call controller function and pass value

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a function in the c# controller and pass a value but I am getting the following error: `'Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference'.
I added the Driver Model as well.
Thank you in advance for the help.

**JS**

```
function getDrivers(lastName) 
{
    console.log(lastName);
    return $http.post(baseUrl + 'Admin/getDrivers', { lastName: lastName })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(1);
    }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        console.log(2);
    });
}
```

**C# Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getDrivers(DriverModel model)
        {

            JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
            try
            {
                jsonResult.Data = model.GetDrivers(model.lastName);
                return jsonResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return jsonResult;
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
vm.getMatches = function (searchText) {
if (searchText.length > 1)
{
    getDrivers(searchText);
}
```

Comment: The error is not related to the code you posted here.. Can you check once

Comment: Thank you.I added the rest of my code

Comment: Can you post the code for `DriverModel`.

Comment: Thank you. I added the driver model.

Comment: Your `GetDrivers` method takes in the last name but it isn't used in the query at all so you are returning the full list of all drivers on that table.  Is that what you want?  Are you able to step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: I will change the method and filter the driver by last name later. Now I just want to solve the error. No I was not able to step to step to the getDrivers in the controller.

Comment: I was way off.... Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602155/unable-to-get-property-then-of-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be getting to the controller because the getDrivers function is being posted expecting to find the function getDrivers with a parameter named "lastname" but in your controller the parameter is named "model" which should probably be a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your $http promise callback isn't returning a value. That means it will return `undefined`, as opposed to the promise you probably want it to be returning.

Additionally, `success` and `error` have been deprecated in favor of `then` and `catch`. Something you may want to consider.

Comment: Thank you. My http post is not hitting the function in the control at all. Why is that?

Comment: You mean the C# controller? The post isn't hitting the server? I'm not sure why that would be, have you checked the network tab in the chrome dev tools to ensure that you're hitting the correct endpoint?